# reload dll functions from another dll, C#

Tags: c#, dll

I have 2 unmanaged dlls which have exactly same set of function (but slightly different logic).

How can I switch between these 2 ddls during runtime?

now I have:

```
[DllImport("one.dll")]
public static extern string _test_mdl(string s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on the existing answers here. You comment that you don't want to change existing code. You don't have to do that.

```
[DllImport("one.dll", EntryPoint = "_test_mdl")]
public static extern string _test_mdl1(string s);

[DllImport("two.dll", EntryPoint = "_test_mdl")]
public static extern string _test_mdl2(string s);

public static string _test_mdl(string s)
{
    if (condition)
        return _test_mdl1(s);
    else
        return _test_mdl2(s);
}
```

You keep using _test_mdl in your existing code, and just place the if-statement in a new version of that method, calling the correct underlying method.

Comment: that should kinda work, but I'll need to wrap around all the functions form dlls :(

Answer (score 4):

Define them in different C# classes?

```
static class OneInterop
{
 [DllImport("one.dll")]
 public static extern string _test_mdl(string s);
}

static class TwoInterop
{
 [DllImport("two.dll")]
 public static extern string _test_mdl(string s);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you would need two classes.

Comment: You can set the `EntryPoint` property in the `DllImport` attribute if you wanted to keep them in the same class.

Comment: i thought about it, but he problem is that I use _test_mdl() alot in the project, and if I make it like in your example, I will need to change code and use if-statement for every call of _test_mdl

Answer (score 4):

I haven't ever had to use this, but I think the EntryPoint can be specified in the declaration.  Try this:

```
    [DllImport("one.dll", EntryPoint = "_test_mdl")]
    public static extern string _test_mdl1(string s);

    [DllImport("two.dll", EntryPoint = "_test_mdl")]
    public static extern string _test_mdl2(string s);
```

[DllImportAttribute.EntryPoint Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint(v=VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could still use dynamic loading and call `LoadLibraryEx` (P/Invoke), `GetProcAddress` (P/Invoke) and `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` (System.Runtime.InterOpServices).

;)